# Lenovo T400 fan running constantly in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thinkpad, kubuntu

I recently installed Kubuntu 12.04 on a partition of my hard drive and the CPU fan seems to be constantly running. I thought it might be because it was running hot but the temp is floating around 110 degrees F with a load of around 2-12%. I also though the CPU might not be scaling and running at full speed all the time, but that is not the case either. I have the cpufrequtils installed and set to ondemand.

As a test I logged into windows to see the differences, in W7 the temp and load is about the same, but the fan does not run constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try:

1. ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059548&page=4)) Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, look for the line that loads
   your linux system. It should look something like this:

   > linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-1-amd64
   >   root=UUID=addaasa-abcd-1234-a51g-5g4uudh4vak ro  quiet splash

   Add the option acpi_os="Linux" like so:

   > linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-1-amd64
   >   root=UUID=badedbe2-adbc-4638-a41b-4a03fe7432cb ro  quiet splash
   >   **acpi_osi="Linux"**

   Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.
2. For tips on controlling a lenovo's fan, have a look at [this page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed). The thinkwiki webpage in general is always a great source of info for linux on lenovo machines.
3. If you are on a Dell machine (I know you are not, but someone else may read this), use the i8k module: 
   sudo apt-get install i8kutils 
   sudo modprobe i8k
   sudo i8kfan 0 1
4. If you are dual booting with windows, check the fan settings there. I had a similar problem and the power settings in windows were making changes in the BIOS which then would affect my linux system as well.