# Notebook fan spinning at max after trying Linux

Tags: windows, linux, fan, thinkpad, noise

I have a Thinkpad T420 (4178-BSG) I use with Windows. The fan (cpu) was always very quiet and I was completely satisfied with it. A few days ago I booted Backtrack Linux from a flashdrive and the fan started to spin at maximum and was very loud. The problem is that this state persists. When I start the Thinkpad and boot Windows as usual the fan start spining at max and never stops. It drives me mad. It looks like somehow the Linux change some settings and I have to suffer. I tried reseting BIOS, updating BIOS, nothing helpes. I even removed the keyboard, looked at the fan but there is no dust.

**Update**
Maybe there is a problem with the integrated Intel GMA 3000 Card. The Power Manager shows it at 100% at all times:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like Linux probably had nothing to do with it and it was just a coincidence. Did you remove the heat sink or loosen its screws at any time?

Comment: Check your CPU activity and [temperature](http://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature) when you are in Windows. Maybe you installed something else in the same time frame which is making the CPU active all the time.

Comment: Another test, leave the computer on a boot select screen for a moment (or in general, any place without a system launching, can even be the bios screen), and see if you have the problem. If yes, you have probably a hardware issue, like David is suggesting.

Comment: Also have a look at my answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/461927/lenovo-t400-fan-running-constantly-in-kubuntu-12-04).

Comment: I made no hardware or software changes. I have Windows 8 and Windows 7 dual booted. I booted Windows 7 after maybe 3 months and the problem is also there so I do not thnik it is a software problem. The fan runs at 3580 RPM even if the temperature is only 47C and the computer is idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is likely that the Linux boot and/or the dual boot with Windows 8 somehow changed the motherboard settings for the fan control. I would proceed with:

- Check the settings for fan control in the ThinkVantage Power Manager (use the Advanced view), see [image: Advance Power settings]. Check if the Linux OS changed essential settings for the predefined power agendas. Especially check the settings for what the computer does when idle.
- Install and use tpfancontrol, see [tpfancontrol](http://www.staff.uni-marburg.de/~schmitzr/donate.html). Maybe that
  program can help you to regain the control of the fan. I have used it
  on a number of Thinkpads, not a flashy interface but works very well. Since you have both W7 and W8, you should probably install it on both OS ([tpfancontrol W8 - works](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=102630)
- TP420 is usually sold with three years of warranty & service.
  Check your warranty - can be done through the ThinkVantage Toolbox.

Also, check out this question and its answer for getting the Linuxversion to work, [Problem w t400 fan w linux](https://superuser.com/q/461927/147104)

Comment: tpfancontrol works ok when I set it to smart mode. But it does seem to work under lockscreen on Windows 8, so when I lock the computer and get away from it for some time the fan spins full

Comment: great that it works! it seems like the fan goes back to the BIOS mode when you lock the screen, will check my configs because that is not the case for my installations

Comment: Checked my installation(s), they are all standard ones (I have adjusted the fan control though), didn't find anything that relates to the screensaver issue you raised.

Comment: It so not screensacer, the display turns of after some time and then the fan starts spinning. I read rhe whole config and I do not think there is a way to change this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe it is a Powersetting issue. If you have the Thinkvantage Powermanager installed, you can change what the system does depending on activity

Comment: I updated my question, maybe it is graphic card related

Comment: Select the "Advanced" part of the Power manager. In this section, you can control the settings on a more detailed level, especially when & how of energy consumption (and fan).

Comment: it is set the same way as Bios, balanced on battery an pefromance on AC and the fans spin at max even on battery

Comment: So it works as it should when you use tpfancontrol and when the computer has been inactive, the fan goes back to max?

Comment: yes. My Power Manager looks like your screenshot, the settings are the same as in BIOS and look ok